# Are homotopy types of finite CW complexes countable?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need help with solving this problem. I came across this in a paper called "Counting homotopy types of manifolds".

Comment: Sentences start with a upper case letter. They end with some punctuation. All upper case words are aggressive to the eyes : use *italic* or **bold**. Plus the question lacks what you have tried in order to solve the problem. *If* you make an effort asking the question, *then* we might make one as well by answering it.

Answer (score 3):

Every finite CW complex has the homotopy type of a finite simplicial complex, and the latter are clearly countable.